# SQL: Query to insert records into the table if there is not even one record with certain condition

Tags: postgresql, cte, bulk-insert

I have a table train_statuses.
With the schema as below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.train_statuses (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    status text NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);

Indexes:
    "train_statuses_id_updated_at_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id, updated_at)
    "idx_train_statuses_id_updated_at" btree (id, updated_at)
```

This table can have multiple entries for the same id.
The status can be one among these values : `'cancelled', 'queued','executed', 'failed', 'succeeded'`

Now I need to write a query that inserts entries into `train_statuses` for all ids that has their status only as either `queued` or `executed` with status as 'cancelled'

I came up with this query

```sql
WITH ts AS (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT ON (ts.id) ts.id, ts.status
        FROM train_statuses ts
        INNER JOIN train_statuses t ON ts.id = t.id
        WHERE 
            ts.status IN ('queued','executed') 
            AND ts.status NOT IN ('failed', 'succeeded','cancelled')
    )
    INSERT INTO train_statuses (id, updated_at, status) SELECT id, now(), 'cancelled' FROM ts
```

This technically works.
But I feel there would be a more optimal way to get this done.

Joining `train_statuses` again with itself doesn't seem that great since the table size is around `150GB` and we `don't have index on status`.

Please go through and let me know if there is a better way to get the desired result.

Thanks

Note: If there is any better title for this question please add an edit suggestion.

Comment: (1) `ts.status IN ('queued','executed')` is excess - `status` is defined as NOT NULL. (2) NOT IN is slow - use NOT EXISTS. (3) `ts.status` selected in CTE is not used - remove it.

Comment: So, train_statuses can have multiple records for one id ?

Comment: Yes it can have multiple records @GerardH.Pille

Comment: Can *the same train* be cancelled or queued, or whatever, multiple times too?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. There are no restrictions.

Comment: Therefore – and please correct me if I'm wrong – this is not about trains having their status as either `queued` or `executed` but rather about those having their **latest** status as either `queued` or `executed`, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct @AndriyM

Comment: Also, the size of the `train_statuses` table is 150GB. Have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed superfluous joins and criteria

```
WITH ts AS (
        SELECT ts.id
         FROM train_statuses ts
         WHERE ts.status IN ('queued','executed')
        EXCEPT
        SELECT ts.id
         FROM train_statuses ts
         WHERE ts.status Not IN ('queued','executed')
)
    INSERT INTO train_statuses (id, updated_at, status) SELECT id, now(), 'cancelled' FROM ts
```

Comment: In PostgreSQL, [it's `EXCEPT`, not `MINUS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html). Other than that, an important detail has just come up in the question's comment section that's likely going to invalidate your otherwise neat solution.

Comment: @AndriyM you're awful but I like you.

Comment: I aim to please, even though I'm awful at that